# How can I make slivers do not appear behind a pinned sliver after scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to place a pinned `SliverAppBar` on the top of the page while the user can scroll the SliverList. The problem arises from the fact the body of the `Scaffold` ia a gradient and the pinned `SliverAppBar` shouldn't have a background color (hence it's currently transparent). So when the user scrolls, the `SliverList` contents appear behind the `SliverAppBar` which is not the desired effect.

Here's a minimal reproducible code of the problem

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Regular AppBar'),
      ),
      body: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.teal, Colors.red],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'A widget that must be before SliverAppBar',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SliverAppBar(
              surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              pinned: true,
              title: Text(
                'Sliver AppBar',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('#$index item'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo before the scroll:
[image: Demo before the scroll]
Demo after the scroll:
[image]

If the Scaffold's body didn't had to be a gradient, I'd just make the background color of the `SliverAppBar` the same as the `Scaffold`'s, but I can't do that because the hard edges are going to appear.

I have tried using `SliverOverlapAbsorber` and `SliverOverlapInjector` and replacing the `CustomScrollView` with a `NestedScrollView` but I think I missed the point of these two first widgets. I just want to the items not to appear behind the `SliverAppBar`, that's all.

Thanks in advance to any replies!